# How can I remove certain parts of a word document?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, find-and-replace

I have a word document filled with Physics equations and annotations. I want another word document to be a copy of the first document but with the annotations removed.

I have all the annotations in grey text. Is there any way to remove all grey text in a word document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is: using `Find & Replace...`.

At the bottom of the `Find & Replace...` dialog box, click the button called `More...`.

It will open more options.  In the bottom, again, you will find some `Format` option; click on it and you will be presented with some options, including `Font`.

clicking on it will present you with a font dialog box; select the format you want (i.e. your grey text).  This means that you will be searching for text formatted with grey font, and will substitute it with nothing; this will eliminate the grey text.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different style for annotations. Once you finish with those, you can change the style font property to "hidden". 
This will not remove annotations from the document (that is someone can see them), but they will not be visible on the screen or on printed document.
To get them back you uncheck the style font property back.

If you want to remove all of those, there is an option (in the styles palette) to select all the text with a given style, so you can remove it at once. Of course you would not be able to have it back, so store the original document.